# How to add google sign in button using spring boot security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to add a google sign-in button.
I have config like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(a -> a
                        .antMatchers("/", "/error", "/test", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(fl -> fl.loginPage("/test.html"))
                .exceptionHandling(e -> e
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                )
                .csrf(c -> c
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                )
                .logout(l -> l
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                )
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

and I have `index.html` page with google button, but this button doesn't look like google sign-in button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SignIn</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<header th:insert="fragments/header.html :: emptyNav"></header>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want using `spring-security` for social login and get google sign-in button with google styles.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

`Google sign-in` uses OAuth2 authentication.

1. You need register your application in Google (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)
2. Get your CLIENT_CODE and CLIENT_SECRET for access of your application
3. Implement 'password' OAuth2 workflow in your application (for example, button calls controller's method, it calls service where you make request to Google with `Authorization: Basic Base64(CLIENT_CODE:CLIENT_SECRET)` and form with user login/password).